# How can I update quantity of the product in UI, immediately at the time of updating the database?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setProduct(data))
}, [id]);

const handleDeliveredBtn = id => {
    const newQuantity = parseInt(quantity) - 1;
    const updatedQuantity = { newQuantity };

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            toast('Product delivered successfully.');
        })
};
```

I want to show the **updatedQuantity** in my **UI**. Quantity is updated at database. But, without **reloading** the page, I can't see any changes that happen in my **UI**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setProduct to cause a render. React components only render whenever there is a change in the state or props, which in your case is invoked by the `setProduct`.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setProduct(data))
}, [id]);

const handleDeliveredBtn = id => {
    const newQuantity = parseInt(quantity) - 1;
    const updatedQuantity = { newQuantity };

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            toast('Product delivered successfully.');
            setProduct(data) // add setProduct
        })
};
```

You might want to make a shallow copy instead for performance / unnessecary renders but for the sake of example I just added `setProduct(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `useState` hook to display updated value in your UI. checkout below code:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
const [updatedQuantity, setUpdatedQuantity] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setProduct(data))
}, [id]);

const handleDeliveredBtn = id => {
    const newQuantity = parseInt(quantity) - 1;
    setUpdatedQuantity(newQuantity);

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            toast('Product delivered successfully.');
        })
};
```

now you can use `updatedQuantity` as a current data in your UI.